# What is $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{e^x}{x+1}\right)}{x^2}\;?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital, elementary-functions

I've been trying to solve this limit, but can't really seem to be able to without using l'Hospital's rule (which the textbook specifically forbids). Here goes: $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{e^x}{x+1}\right)}{x^2}\;.$$

I've messed up once already, since I tried to use arithmetic of limits, ended up getting $0$ as the answer (which is supposed to be $0.5$), only to realise that I can't use arithmetic of limits for this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: $\ln(e^x/(x+1))=x-\log(1+x).$

Comment: Yes, exactly the point where I got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Expand the top as $$\ln (\frac{e^x}{1+x}) =\ln(e^x)-\ln(1+x)=x-\ln(1+x)$$ Then look at the Maclaurin expansion for $\ln(1+x)$, and you'll notice that the $x$ terms cancel and there is a $x^2$ term that cancels with the denominator yielding your limit.

Comment: I didn't notice that it is $\ln(e^{x})$ I was writing it in a Taylor series. Lol me..

Comment: I am afraid this solution wouldn't amount to much, as at this point, you aren't supposed to know Maclaurin/Taylor expansions. Is there a way to calculate this differently?

Comment: Do you know calculus? There is L'hopital's rule.

Comment: I can't, it's in the question.

Comment: The only way I know how to do this is to expand the functions in their power series. Have you defined these functions in their power series yet?

Comment: Well, I have, but unfortunately the textbook confines you to using things pre-l’Hospital, so series and l’Hospital are off limits. One limit that I was able to use repeatedly in this textbook to great avail was $lim_{x/to0} \frac{ln(x+1)}{x}=0$